# Add line number to compiled class

Tags: java, jar, decompiler, jd-eclipse

I'm debugging a 3rd party proprietary jar. JD-eclipse generates the source just fine but I can't add breakpoints into the generated source code. 
Eclipse complains the class file lacks line number info. 
Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no workaround. If the original class was compiled without debug info it's lost to you - there's no way you can fabricate it out of the void.

Comment: I have a feeling it can be done (at least in principle). Why can the decompiler generate understandable code but the debugger can't debug it? What if I regenerate all source code with the decompiler and then compile it with debug info?